# C++ this (what would be a link to current class in such situation)

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, this, std

So having:

```
struct A { void foo(int) { } }; 

typedef std::function<void(int)>   Function;
typedef std::vector<Function>      FunctionSequence;
typedef FunctionSequence::iterator FunctionIterator;

FunctionSequence funcs;

A a;

funcs.push_back(std::bind(&A::foo, &a, std::placeholders::_1));
funcs.push_back(std::bind(&B::bar, &b, std::placeholders::_1));

// this calls a.foo(42) then b.bar(42):
for (FunctionIterator it(funcs.begin()); it != funcs.end(); ++it)
    (*it)(42);
```

If we were inside class `A` subscribing `funcs.push_back` would we say instead of  `&a` `this`

Comment: If you're in C++0x, use a lambda expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly your question, the answer should be yes. `&variable` is always equal to `this` as seen by the instance methods called over `variable`.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it sounds logical, but it's just a guess.

subscribing from inside `A`, would you like to store callback to this particular instance of `A`. If yes then you need `this`.

we don't know your needs, and I can imagine cases where all three variants (`&a`, `&b` or `this`) are correct.